# Python: removing commas from list so that i can import data into separate cells in Excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list, pandas

I'm a newcomer to coding and am using Python 3.6. I am writing some code for an engineering application which involves storing data in lists based upon inputs. Basically I want to be able to export the data to Microsoft Excel so that it is stored in separate cells. I have shown a simplified example below (not prompting the user for an input to keep things simple).

```
import pandas as pd

a = [0, 12.5, 25, 37.5, 50, 62.5, 75, 87.5, 100, 112.5, 125, 137.5, 150, 162.5, 175, 187.5, 200, 212.5, 225, 237.7955263, 250]

k =len(a)

print(k)

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data for a_values.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a (mm)': [a[0], a[1], a[2],
a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7],
a[8], a[9], a[10], a[11], a[12],
a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17],
a[18], a[19], a[20]]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ex.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

I have to do this for many different lists so is there a way of me being able to write out the a[0], a[1].. etc. statement in a much more succinct way using some sort of equation linked to k?

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the DataFrame like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a (mm)': a})
```

Comment: Thanks! How would the code change if I wanted to add one zero at the end of the list (so that each element of the original list 'a' appeared in a separate Excel cell and then a zero appeared in a separate cell at the end?

Comment: Right after print(k) add this line: a.append(0)

Comment: Thanks for the help!